# Let V be the set of functions from C → C. V is a vector space over C, as well as R, with respect to point wise addition of

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $V$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Then $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, as well as $\mathbb{R}$, with the pointwise addition and usual scalar multiplication.
> Consider the following subsets of $V$:
>
> 1. $\{f \in V : f(−t) = \overline{f(t)} \textrm{ for all } t \in \mathbb{C}\}$;
> 2. $\{f \in V : f(-t) = −\overline{f(t)} \textrm{ for all } t \in \mathbb{C}\}$,
>
> where $\bar{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Are they subspaces of $V$?

I understand that $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace, but over $\mathbb{C}$, it seems to me this is not true, since if $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then
$zf(-t) = z\overline{f(t)} \ne \overline{zf(t)}.$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To determine if $V$ is a vector space over $X$, you need to check that if $a,b \in X$ and $\vec{u},\vec{v} \in V$, then

1. $\vec{u} + \vec{v} \in V$
2. $a\vec{u} \in V$

Can you try that with your spaces?

Comment: i just a need an answer, i mean i want to check myself

Comment: @Raghu this site is not a place where other people will solve your homework for you. If you want to understand how to do the problem, I am happy to guide you through it, but you will have to show some effort. This is also the reason for downvotes and close votes on your question -- people here want to see you put some effort into the problem.

Comment: it is not as scalar multication is not closed ,right?

Comment: @Raghu What specifically makes you think that scalar multiplication is not closed?  That sounds like you just said that without actually thinking it to be true just to get us off of your back about not having an attempt.

Comment: the vector space is over the complex field so cf(-t)= c* conjugate of f(t)

Comment: it is not equal to cojugate(cf(t))

Comment: @Raghu that is correct, if you are considering $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$, then that would pose a problem. How about $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: V over R , then it is . i would like to know abt over C. it is not right?

Comment: @Raghu correct :) had you included all that in the body of your question, (a) there would likely be no downvotes and close votes, (b) it would be much easier to help you and (c) you would have quickly gotten an answer "on the point" -- please consider describing the context of the question next time

Comment: @Raghu I have modified your question to rephrase what you were really asking.

Comment: @gt6989b thnks  will mke sure this won't happen again